# Airplane mode and wifi runs simuntaneously in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I am using windows 8.1 pro ver: 6.3.9600 build 9600 
in my laptop when i turn on airplane mode at the same time the wifi can also be turn on or turn off. generaly it should not be happen and all wireless aplication shoud be turn off while airplane mode is on. i can not understand what is the solution and why this accurs?
the screen shots given here is clear more about problem.
[image]

Comment: if you turn off Airplane mode before the wireless devices are initialized, the devices stay off even though Airplane mode is off. Maybe it works and when you turn it on.. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2826798

Answer (score -1):

This is the normal behavior in Windows 8.1. I don't know why Microsoft has done this but it is normal.
Just don't turn on wifi if you have enabled airplane mode

Answer (score -1):

This is normal for all devices and is working the way it is designed. You are able to override the Wireless on/off state in airplane mode because you are allowed to use wireless on airplanes.

The same has been true of bluetooth and all other wireless-enabled devices ever since wireless was invented.